# Selecionar uma linha em que uma coluna tenha um elemento de um CSV

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-select, csv

Eu tenho uma tabela no banco de dados com a seguinte estrutura:

```
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| numeros | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+---------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Nela, eu tenho os seguintes valores:

```
+----+-------------------------------------+
| id | numeros                             |
+----+-------------------------------------+
|  1 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 |
|  2 | 1,3,5,9,11,13,15                    |
|  3 | 2,4,6,8,10,12                       |
|  4 | 1                                   |
|  5 | 15                                  |
+----+-------------------------------------+
```

`numeros` é uma coluna que contém valores separados por vírgula (CSV).
Como posso selecionar as linhas que contenham algum número desse conjunto?

Por exemplo, selecionar todas as linhas em que a coluna `numeros` contenha o valor `1`.

Eu tentei fazer casos como:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE `numeros` LIKE '%1%';
+----+-------------------------------------+
| id | numeros                             |
+----+-------------------------------------+
|  1 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 |
|  2 | 1,3,5,9,11,13,15                    |
|  3 | 2,4,6,8,10,12                       |
|  4 | 1                                   |
|  5 | 15                                  |
+----+-------------------------------------+
```

Neste caso ele acaba selecionando todos que tenham o número 1, literalmente. Como é o caso das linhas 3 e 5.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM `tabela` WHERE `numeros` LIKE '%1,%';
+----+-------------------------------------+
| id | numeros                             |
+----+-------------------------------------+
|  1 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 |
|  2 | 1,3,5,9,11,13,15                    |
+----+-------------------------------------+
```

Já neste, parece funcionar bem, mas a linha 4 não é selecionada.

Fora que, eu tenho tentado evitar o `LIKE`, já que esse número será digitado pelo usuário. E como sempre dizem, [nunca confie na entrada do usuário](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ee798441(v=cs.20).aspx), ainda mais para um caso como o do `LIKE`.

Comment: Os números sempre são salvos de forma ordenada?

Comment: Não, e o número 1 foi só um exemplo, teria que funcionar para qualquer outro número

Comment: Sim, mas a lista de números seria ordenada sempre?

Comment: Não, já que o servidor aceita qualquer tipo de CSV, que contenha números então funcionaria com `4,1,3,5`, por exemplo

Comment: Ahh, então é mais complicado :)

Comment: É, quebrei muito a cabeça com isso aí haha

Comment: Como é mysql, as opções são mais restritas. Usando o like você precisaria testar todos os casos que são: Único elemento na lista, elemento começando a lista, elemento no meio de 2 elementos da lista, e elemento terminando a lista. Pensou em fazer dessa forma? Não sugiro como resposta pois não seria muito elegante, mas daria pra resolver.

Comment: 1 mude o modelo , normalize esta tabela 2 mude o modelo , normalize esta tabela 3 não sendo possível aplique um "unpivot" nesta coluna , mysql não tem pronto que eu saiba mas existem soluções de contorno --- voc~e deve repensar um modelo quando respostas que deveriam ser simples se tornam complicadas.

Comment: Qual o/a modelo/normalização certo/a para fazer isso?

Comment: Colocando na 3FN você não teria mais uma coluna multivalorada. Essa coluna seria uma tabela nova com uma chave estrangeira para a tabela que a originou. Aí seria moleza ajustar a consulta usando as 2 tabelas.

Comment: A única alternativa seria criar outra tabela? Eu estou pensando na agilidade da consulta. Imagine que eu teria vários usuários. Esses números seriam como recursos que eles tem. Eu queria consultar todos os usuários que possuem um certo recurso. Não ficaria muito pesado quando eu juntar muitos usuários e muitos recursos? Não só pesado em tamanho de pedido, mas pesado em espaço em disco.

Comment: Tente LIKE '%,@num,%' sendo @num um parâmetro de entrada do usuário.

Comment: Victor, no seu caso, acabou não pegando nenhuma linha da tabela como especificado acima.

Comment: Tente entao like '%,'||@num||',%' testei aqui e parece que funcionou.

Comment: Esse daí não deu certo comigo não

Comment: Não alterar o modelo implica em um sql complexo para fazer uma coisa simples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar a função *FIND_IN_SET()* para encontrar a substring no conjunto, por exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE FIND_IN_SET('3', numeros);
```

Vai retornar todos que contenham o elemento 3:

```
| id |                             numeros |
|----|-------------------------------------|
|  1 | 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 |
|  2 |                    1,3,5,9,11,13,15 |
|  6 |                               3,1,8 |
```

Comment: Nunca ia imaginar que existiria isso aí. Muito obrigado cara!